# gets.chomp to match ENTER (in ruby)

Tags: ruby

I thought that (in a while...do loop)

```
    gets.chomp != ''
```

might match a carriage return from a terminal. It doesn't. What am I not understanding? Thank you.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in irb. It is hard to diagnose the issue without seeing the complete code-segment.

Answer (score 1):

[String#chomp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) removes carriage returns from the string it is being called on.

If you remove `chomp` it should give you the expected output. See below:

```
2.1.2 :001 > def foo
2.1.2 :002?>   while true do
2.1.2 :003 >       puts gets != ''
2.1.2 :004?>     end
2.1.2 :005?>   end
 => :foo
2.1.2 :006 > foo
a
true
b
true
c
true
1
true
2
true
# about to press enter
true

true
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I had assumed they meant `while gets.chomp != '' do <loop-body> end`